# JavaScript function arguments store by reference

Tags: javascript

Not sure if this is the correct way to word my question.  If I set up the following piece of JavaScript code:

```
var x = 5;
var y = function(z) {
    z=7;
    return z;
}
y(x);
x;
```

I get `7` returned from the function call but `x` stays its original value.  I thought JavaScript variables call by reference so how come `x`'s value isn't actually changed through the function?

Comment: Primitives are passed by value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem here is that you're not mutating anything; you're just reassigning the variable `z` in the function. It wouldn't make a difference if you passed an object or array.

```
var x = ['test'];
var y = function(z) {
    z=['foo'];
    return z;
}
y(x);
x; // Still ['test']
```

---

Now, what others have said is also true. **Primitives cannot be mutated**. This is actually more interesting than it sounds, because the following code works:

```
> var x = 1;
> x.foo = 'bar';
"bar"
> x
1
> x.foo
undefined
```

Notice how the assignment to `x.foo` was seemingly successful, yet `x.foo` is nowhere to be found. That's because JavaScript readily coerces primitive types and object types (there are "object" versions of primitives, that are normal objects). In this case, the primitive `1` is being coerced into a new object (`new Number(1)`), whose `foo` attribute is getting set, and then it is promptly destroyed, so no lasting effects occur.

Comment: Oh ok. So when I reassign `z` in the function, `z` and `x` don't point to the same array/object?  I thought that's what calling by reference meant. Could you help me understand what I'm not getting? Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: @user2066880 - They are the same object until you reassign `z` inside the function. Up to then, you could use `z` to modify the object, and those modifications would be seen in the calling code. If you replaced `z=['foo'];` in this code with `z[0] = 'foo';`, then `x` in the calling code would be changed to `['foo']`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @TeddHopp about this note:

> Only the value is passed for all variables, not just primitives. You
>   cannot change a variable in the calling code by passing it to a
>   function. (Granted, you can change the object or array that may be
>   passed; however, the variable itself remains unchanged in the calling
>   code.)

If you want the value of `x` to change anyways you can do:

```
x = y(x);
```

Comment: Only the value is passed for all variables, not just primitives. You cannot change a variable in the calling code by passing it to a function. (Granted, you can change the object or array that may be passed; however, the variable itself remains unchanged in the calling code.)

Comment: Thanks. you learn something new everyday. guess I'm more used to Java :)